# Xcode: Custom TabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am creating an application that i want to have instead of the normal `UITabBarController` i want to make mine so it can scroll;

So i Started by creating a simple window based application and programmatically created my `UITabBar` and `UIScrollBar` set both their frames correctly and removed the `self.window.rootViewController = viewController1;` portion of the code so that my app shows the `scrollview`with the `tabbar` and not my `UIViewController`

So this far everithing works as expected.

the problem goes when launching my viewControllers, i currently am using:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{

    if (item.tag == 2) {
        UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:viewController2 animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```

the problem is that this does work but the view controller is in front of the tabbar so i can't use it to switch views again.

i have tried changing the frame of the view in the viewController so its small enough to fit the scrollview with the tab bar but it just ignores this part, so im kind of stuck here.

if anyone could point me in the right direction or tell me if im ignoring some option that i have to set will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably don't want to do this. In one of the WWDC videos, the presenter explicitly stated scrollable tab bars as an example of a confusing interface that you should avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why make things difficult? just make UIButtons with custom images(images like TabBar "buttons") and put the button in a scrollview ;)

Comment: but still will have the issue where the pushed view controller will be on top of those buttons, which would mean to add the buttons in all my viewControllers, not just on the window.

Comment: import from one view controller... ;) and just add in the - (void)viewDidLoad {} in every window ;)

Comment: Hey man, I find somelinks that might help: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/infinitabbar  http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ciexpandabletabbar

Comment: wow rafa thats a nice find! not exactly what i was looking for since this is with page controll! but still a great place to start off!